# tooltip for textfield on mouseclick in extjs4

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a textfield, to that  i need to set a tooltip, but in extjs i found 
    that tooltip comes on mouseover, is there any posibility to show 
    tooltip on mouseclick,

Thansk Advance
Rajesh

Answer (score 0):

Try this sample.

```
Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
        width: 200,
        bodyPadding: 5,
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        items: [{
            xtype: 'textfield',
            name: 'name',
            listeners: {
                render: function(c) {
                    this.getEl().on('mousedown', function(e, t, eOpts) {
                        // call to show your tooltip
                    }); 
                }
            }
        }]
    });​
```